# Construct a url from HTML form input using jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to construct a URL using the users input from the HTML form after they click on the submit button. Using that, I want to construct a URL that will retrieve data from an API. Down below is my code

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <form>
        <label for="token">Domain Name: (xxxx.intructure.com)</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="domain" name="domain" placeholder="domain">
        <br>
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>  
</html>
```

```js
var domain = $('.input[name=domain]').val();

var myUrl = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://${domain}.instructure.com/api/v1/courses`

var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": myUrl,
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Authorization": "Bearer 8415~GFtFLYvN4M9iuiIppWycSHqbC54nfDQMMnbJAOXhJp9efTK04GE6XxWsOq6qFniY"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response) 
})
```

Comment: So what's the problem you're having? You haven't exactly stated what you need help with, just what you are doing.

Comment: It looks like your code is running immediately as it loads into the browser. You need to add a click or submit handler to run your code only after the user submits the form.

Comment: @kmoser how would I add a submit handler. Should I do an onclick in the submit button?

Comment: @skully the code is not able to connect to the API using the URL. It is giving an undefined value in the ${domain} variable in the URL. It is not able to retrieve the users response and input the domain variable, and then input that into the myURL variable.

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript is executing immediately when the page is loaded, you haven't attached it to listen to your button and whenever it's clicked.

```js
$("#submit-button").click(function() { // Trigger whenever the submit button is clicked.
    let domain = $("#domain").val();
    let settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://" + domain + ".instructure.com/api/v1/courses",
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Authorization": "Bearer 8415~GFtFLYvN4M9iuiIppWycSHqbC54nfDQMMnbJAOXhJp9efTK04GE6XxWsOq6qFniY"
        }
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) { // Send GET request.
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <form>
    <label for="token">Domain Name: (xxxx.intructure.com)</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="domain" name="domain" placeholder="domain">
    <br>
    <button id="submit-button">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When the button with the id `submit-button` is clicked, the event listening function will then fetch the input from the domain input and trigger your GET request.